# Why doesn't execute() return true on error?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Please take a look at my code:

```
try {
    // db connection here
    $stm = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable(id,token) values(NULL,$token)")->execute(); 

} catch(PDOException $e){
    if ( $stm ){
        echo 'inserting fails';
    } else {
        echo 'something else is wrong';
    }
}

-- `token` column is unique
```

**Current outputs:**

- The row inserted successfully.
- It prints `something else is wrong` error for both {duplicate entry} and {SQL syntax}

**Expected outputs:**

- The row inserted successfully.
- It prints `inserting fails` error for {duplicate entry}
- It prints `something else is wrong` error for {SQL syntax}

---

Ok, if I write my code like following *(without chaining)*, then expected output happens:

```
$stm = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable(id,token) values(NULL,$token)");
$stm->execute();
```

Well I want to know, when can I chain those PDO statements?

Comment: This is called "fluent interface" you might want to read/google this, so you get a better understanding how they work in PHP and then why it doesn't work for your current code.

Comment: The real question is, *why would you want to*?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I asked this question because I've chained the most of my queries so far *(in my codes)*. So I want to know should I change all of them? or being chain would be fine?

Comment: Why not start by ditching the NULL as the first parameter. Be eco-friendly.

Comment: @JayBlanchard All those "cool and fancy" [frameworks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/laravel?sort=newest) do that. *And who doesn't want to do the same "fancy" code too?* :P

Comment: If you're just going to stick variables into the SQL instead of binding parameters, why not just use `query` instead of chaining `prepare` and `execute`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic In reality there is some parameters that I need to pass them as prepared statement.

Comment: I know, I know @Rizier123 SMH :P

Comment: Downvoters may you please leave a message and explain why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exception can only be thrown in either the `prepare` or `execute` methods. Either of those is going to happen before `$stm =`. In other words, *if* an exception is going to be thrown, the assignment to `$stm` is *always* going to be skipped, meaning the variable doesn't exist at all in your `catch` block. Therefore it can only evaluate to `false`, and will in fact produce a notice about being undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Read the PDO documentation http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php and look at the return values. You can only chain when an object is returned such as a statement or resultset.

Execute (http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) returns a boolean, not an object so we know it cannot be chained. 
Prepare (http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) returns a statement object, so we can use the return statement to chain on another method call.

Think of it like this:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("..sql..");
$bool = $stmt->execute();
```

This can translate into:

```
$bool = $dbh->prepare("..sql..")->execute();
```

As the return from ->prepare() is the the $stmt.

Comment: Well said young Jedi.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you aren't getting your expected output is that the way you have it written, any time you get a `PDOException`, `$stm` can never be true. If either the `prepare` or the `execute` fails, then `$stm` will be undefined.

I originally thought that you could fix this by removing the check for `execute` success from the `catch` block, but I was mistaken. You cannot get your expected output while still chaining the methods.

```
try {
   $success = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable(id,token) values(NULL,$token)")->execute();
   if (!$success) {
       // This can never be reached. If your have set PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION, then either
       // the query is successful and $success === true, or the prepare or the execute
       // failed, and an exception will be thrown 
       echo 'inserting fails';
   }
} catch(PDOException $e){
    echo 'something else is wrong';
}
```

Comment: I just realized that this is wrong after reading @deceze answer. `$stm` won't be false, and this won't work. I forgot that execute will cause an exception as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record. To answer the question the guy tried to ask.

A code from my [article on PDO](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#errors) (also fixing an SQL injection):

```
try {
    $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO mytable(token) values(?)")->execute([$token]);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    if ($e->getCode() == 1062) {
        // insert failed due to duplicate key error
        echo "duplicate token";
    } else {
        // insert failed due to any other error
        throw $e;
    }
}
```